# Plotting contour line from three matrices

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two vectors `A(1,512)`, `B(1,8`) , and one matrix `C(8,512)`. I am trying to plot contour by using `contour(X,Y,Z)`. I do not know to do it. 
`A` vector represents distance, `B` vector is frequency, and `C` matrix is velocity.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. `A`, `B` and `C` are vectors, you cannot find contours in any of them. You can plot `A` vs `B` as a 2D plot through `plot(A,B)`. I don't know what you mean with "at `Y-axis`" or how `C` relates to `A` and `B`. Please clarify your post.

Comment: It sounds like you want to plot contours of A and B at values of C but how will you arrange A and B in the X-Y plane?  Also you mention an example, what example? Sadly this question makes no sense... [ask]

Comment: This is **still** unclear. What contour do you want to plot? Could you please clarify what the desired outcome is?

Comment: @ Justin and  Cris Luengo. Thank you, I was trying to explain that A and B are vectors and C are 2D-Matrix. That is why I faced problem to plot contour. However, I found the command that can do that. contourf(X,Y,Z)

Comment: @ Cris Luengo. Thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Math with your latest edit, it makes more sense. A and B span the space represented by C.  Glad you found your solution. Could you please post it as an answer for future visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using function `contourf(X,Y,Z)`

```
C1=C';
contourf(B,A,C1);
```

Transposed of `C` used because `length(B)` must equal `size(C,2)` and `length(A)` must equal `size(C,1)`

I quote from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html):

> `contourf(X,Y,Z)`, `contourf(X,Y,Z,n)`, and `contourf(X,Y,Z,v)` draw filled contour plots of Z using X and Y to determine the x and y values.